# Custom grid in ExtJs

Tags: extjs

Question regarding ExtJs grid. Currently I have ASP MVC 2.0 project. One page of this project is a very complex grid with a lot of jquery and custom grid. This grid process on server and flush to the client as an html. Now I have to create WCF project that would return JSON array and on the client side I need to retrieve json and display this complex grid too. So, what do you think about ExtJs grid, is it applicable solution for my task? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can totally customize extjs grid (even with jquery). And extjs is in love with json :)